# Select all row from define value username

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

I want to select all row as same username from define value. When i try to

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = $username")
```

> it's not working and get "An error occurred while retrieving data". So
>   i try again with

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE(username='".intval($username)."')")
```

> and it's working find but I'm stuck in get "The database is empty"

```
<?php

$response = array();
if(isset($_GET['username'])){

$username = $_GET['username'];

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect failed:  %S\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE(username='".intval($username )."')"){

    $rowCount = $result->num_rows;
    if($rowCount > 0){
        $response["data"] = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $data = array();

            $data["_id"] = $row["_id"];
            $data["date"] = $row["date"];
            $data["username"] = $row["username"];
            $data["name"] = $row["name"];
            $data["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
            $data["tel"] = $row["tel"];

            array_push($response["data"], $data);
        }
        $response["success"]=1;
    }
    else{
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]="The database is empty.";
    }
$result->close();
    }
else{
    $response["success"]=0;
    $response["message"]="An error occurred while retrieving data.";
}
}
else{
$response["success"]=0;
$response["message"]="Required field(s) is missing.";

}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: why are you use `intval` in your query ??

Comment: Check what is the data type of this column name should be Char or Varchar then

`$db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username LIKE '%{$username}%'");`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM data WHERE username=".$username;

Comment: @Sumitpatel i just try to other but it's not working, can you suggest me can i do. Thank you

Comment: username look like varchar datatype so just do $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = '{$username}'");

Comment: Error with org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: @SutineeManrob, What is the value of `$username`?? Also let me know the field type of `username` of **data** table.

Comment: @FrayneKonok varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one  [variable $username must be surrounded by single quotation 
(') ]

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = '$username'")
```

Comment: Error with org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: java!!! @sutinee manrob you are using mysqli driver and using php why error with java..

Comment: I'm using android studio to retrieve data from mysql database

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) do?

> Returns the integer value of var, using the specified base for the
>   conversion (the default is base 10). intval() should not be used on
>   objects, as doing so will emit an E_NOTICE level error and return 1.

So your query is roughly the same as doing

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (username=0)
```

And naturally since you do not have any username that's '0' you do not get any matches.

The crux of the problem is this:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE(username='".intval($username )."')"
```

You shouldn't be passing parameters like this. You should instead do:

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username=?")
 $stmt->bind_param("s, $username)
 if($db->execute()) }
     // and read this on how to fetch
     // http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
 }
```

Comment: Like this ?

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = ?")){
$stmt->bind_param("s, $username");
$db->execute();

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.